# Is $ \textbf{Set}\ $ a subcategory of $ \textbf{Rel}\ $?

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to get a better understanding of the relationship between the categories $ \textbf{Rel}\ $and $ \textbf{Set}\ $.  From other questions on this site, I  see that there is a (faithful) functor from the former to the latter.  But would it also be correct to say that $ \textbf{Set}\ $is a subcategory of $ \textbf{Rel}\ $? It would seem to be a valid subcategory since the graph of any function $ f \colon A \to B $ is also a subset of $A \times B $ as required for the definition of morphisms in $ \textbf{Rel}\ $, thus making functions a subset of relations.  And of course, the objects are sets in both categories.

Comment: Yes, of course.  You should notice that the compositions are the same (they are), so it is an honest subcategory.